# How to fix: ata7: com reset failed errno=-32?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, encryption

Please be patient and guide me step by step i am a linux noob.

This error occurs when booting. Either that or my crypt' password page shows up and i can't put in the pw. However i can start ubuntu's recovery mode. When i tell him to repair packages he does so and asks me for the crypt pw on command line - then somewhere he has the errno -32 again but "tries after 8 seconds" and is running fine. Then i can start ubuntu normal from the recovery mode page. I also tried telling him to update grub, which doesn't affect anything.

Answer (score 4):

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

If for some reason you can't do the above...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted` and determine which /dev/sdaX is your Ubuntu EXT4 partition
- quit `gparted`
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdaX` # replacing X with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Answer (score 3):

In my case I had a problem with a SATA-connector. After I unplugged the device and plugged it back everything was fixed. Filesystem check shows no errors, everything is perfect.

Comment: I just upvoted this, as somehow exactly this solved that same issue for me as well...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem is an old notebook when trying to install ubuntu.
the solution was to take it apart and clean the sata port.
then everything worked correctly.