# I cannot boot to the desktop because I filled the file system. How do I reclaim some space?

Tags: boot, grub2, data-recovery, desktop-environments

My memory is completely full when I tried following the data recovery and copied the wrong file using command line tool Test Disk. As it was taking so long to copy, I turned it off and I realized I copied the wrong file. Now my laptop memory is now full and lead me to more problems.

I have had similar problems to :

[Ubuntu boots on terminal only, how do I recover the GUI desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/320691/ubuntu-boots-on-terminal-only-how-do-i-recover-the-gui-desktop)

["dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w)

Now my screen keeps blinking:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BN4twl0V8JQ

Can anybody help?
Many thanks. Wish you all the best.

Comment: If you'd have left it running, it is possible that you'd have run out of disk space and you'd have got an error, and could have deleted it straight away. If however it did fit, you could have just deleted the large file. It's likely your issues are mostly from turning your machine off (without allowing it the shutdown).  If it were me, I'd boot a live disk (eg. install media) & `fsck` (do a file system check), then boot it, use a tty (terminal, say ctrl+alt+f4) to login, delete the the file you didn't want - then reboot or restart gui & try logging in normally.

Comment: The "*/dev/sda?: clean   9999/9999 files, 9999/999 blocks*" message is your system doing a `fsck` because it detected an abnormal condition (such as abnormal shutdown the last time it booted because it was turned off) and means little.  It occurs after a certain number of boots (eg. 30) just as preventative maintenance so is nothing to worry about.  The 'clean' is actually good news!

Comment: If it's not graphics card related, this should fix the problem over here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/947126/how-to-fix-ata7-com-reset-failed-errno-32?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: I went on Advanced opttions for ubuntu> recovery mode> fsck> it says "/dev/sda1 is mounted. e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting." Can anybody show me greater detail ???? It would be such a great help. Please help. Thank you. You all the best. I still have very important files on this laptop including family and work. @Dave

Comment: I went on Advanced opttions for ubuntu> recovery mode> fsck> it says "/dev/sda1 is mounted. e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting." Can anybody show me greater detail ???? It would be such a great help. Please help. Thank you. You all the best. I still have very important files on this laptop including family and work.  @guiverc

Comment: You can't fsck (file system check) a mounted file-system, which is why I suggested a 'live' system (eg. install media).  If you boot a thumb-drive & 'try ubuntu', you won't be using your file-system, so `fsck` will be easier. I suggested it as a security-measure I'd do, not that you had to do it. (if errors were there, they would be noticed & corrected). I don't know what filesystem you were using so would need more info to provide command, I'll provide https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilesystemTroubleshooting

Comment: After `fsck` (`xfs_check` or whatever command matches your fs) I'd imagined you'd delete the file you didn't want to copy, and 'filled' your laptop, and hoped with luck, that you could then reboot & everything would hopefully be fine.  If you still have problems, these [additional problems] would most likely be the result of your turning off whilst your drive was writing etc...

Comment: @guiverc I have been trying to do this all day. I cannot sleep without this issue. I don't even know how to delete the file that I didn't want to copy without logging on.  .. I tried rebootin again and again still no error. KEeps going black screen. How do I delete the large file that filled the hard drive? this is so hard.

Comment: @guiverc I checked on "fsck" it says "/dev/sda1 is mounted. e2fsck: cannot continue aborting."

Comment: Please in the future do not shout in the title and include a meaningful one. Thank you. :)