# Cannot login in normal mode after security update (Ubuntu 20.04) 

Tags: boot, 20.04, updates, security

It happened again.  I installed a security update (I restrain the updates to Security updates only) on Ubuntu 20.04 and, after that installation the boot stalls and login never appears.  I could login via Recovery Mode (I use GRUB and select Ubuntu > Advanced > Recovery Mode).  It happened before and I have reinstalled Ubuntu (other time it was looping the login and I found a solution, for which I cannot remember).

I think one of the problems is that I did not notice that it also would security update Proprietary drivers.  I have a NVIDA GTX1080Ti and I have a hunch that it maybe the culprit.

The problem is that I don't even know how to start digging for a solution.

Is there a way to revert the last update?  What else information should I present to help you help me?

Comment: May I ask why you restrict updates to security updates only? This is probably the cause of your issue. Ubuntu isn't windows so you don't have to worry about updates breaking things; updates usually fix problems.

Comment: Also, how did you install the proprietary drivers? Did you use `sudo apt update` and then `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` or did you download and install from the nvidia website (not recommended)?

Comment: @mchid I restrict to security updates only because every time I try to update Ubuntu *something* happens. I know I know it works for most people, but just not for all people. (sorry for the rant, I am pissed with Ubuntu right now)

Comment: Manually installing downloaded Nvidia drivers will cause the system to break every kernel update unless you reinstall the driver after each new kernel. However, the proprietary Nvidia drivers are available through the main and Universe repositories using `apt` so there's no need to manually install.

Comment: @mchid I am not sure but I guess the first time I installed the drivers was from NVIDA website just because I was recovering from an error caused by Ubuntu driver autoupdate.  I somehow forgot to check if it was trying to update Proprietary drivers which I normally leave unchecked.

Comment: So, it will start working if I reinstall Cuda via apt get install?

Answer (score 1):

You can log into recovery mode through GRUB. From there, select the option to do system updates and then run the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

If you run into an error, follow the instructions. Usually, the fix will be to run `sudo apt -f install`. If this doesn't fix the problem, the error message will tell you what else is wrong (usually a missing file or a dependency issue). If you have trouble interpreting the message, just post the error in your question (post a new question) and someone here should be able to know what to do.

Package management can seem overwhelming if you aren't familiar but 99.9% of the time you don't need to reinstall and the fix is quite simple.

---

Manually installing downloaded Nvidia drivers will cause the system to break every kernel update unless you reinstall the driver after each new kernel. However, the proprietary Nvidia drivers are available through the main and Universe repositories using apt so there's no need to manually install.

You can automatically select/install the proprietary Nvidia drivers using the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

---

You can also disable automatic updates so that if there is a problem, you can always deal with it directly and know exactly what's going on.

To disable automatic updates, run the following command to edit a file (**NOTE: you will need to run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt dist-upgrade` daily to keep your system up to date**):

```
nano /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades
```

Edit the file to contain only the following lines:

```
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "0";
APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "0";
APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "0";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "0";
```

After you are done editing, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> to save the changes and then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to exit nano.

---

Lastly, if and when a kernel update causes problems, you can log in to an older kernel through your GRUB menu.

Comment: I followed the instructions but it didn't work.
1) sudo apt update &7 sudo apt dist-upgrade worked without errors.
2) rebooting got COMRESET failed
3) tried to update the drivers with `sudo apt update && sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` no error (nothing to install).

Comment: Now the error is `ata5: COMRESET failed (errno=-32)`

Comment: @FredGuth Okay, that sounds like a [disk problem or maybe a loose SATA cable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/947126/how-to-fix-ata7-com-reset-failed-errno-32). Also, [this related thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/166808/ata-error-comreset-failed-errno-32) says that it might be a full disk (log files filling up the partition).

Comment: Checking thread, but why would a disk problem occur only after I rebooted and why it would not happen in Recovery?

Comment: @FredGuth Yeah, the recovery thing crossed my mind. It could be a coincidence and/or it could be that your partition is now full.

Comment: Partitions are not full.  But the thread you linked reminded me (a little) of what I did to solve last time.  It had to do with a problem of Gnome not being able to write (a chmod thing).  I am not sure if this is related to the problem now, as I can login to gnome in Recovery.

Comment: 20Gb free.  The only other thing that I remember doing that is related to ssd disk is that I moved a .fastai folder from this partition to another disk, but I don't think any .fastai/ file is in my .zshrc ... even if it was, why would it prevent login.

Comment: @FredGuth You can check `journalctl -b` and `sudo journalctl -b` for errors. After the system fails to log into the GUI, start up a TTY and run the commands from there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127067/discussion-between-mchid-and-fred-guth).